# Faster access to nodes in linked list

Tags: performance, language-agnostic, linked-list

Access to nodes in linked lists can get pretty slow if the list gets large. I did think of a way to speed up the access: there is an array (also a LL) with short cuts to every 100th node. This way if I want to get the 205th element, the program will have to go through this "path": `short cut to [100] -> short cut to [200] -> [201] -> ... -> [205]`. This is much faster that going through the whole LL to the 205th element- 5 "steps", instead of 204. Yes, it gets slower if I want the n-hundred-and-99-th element, but the program will skip a large part of the LL to get there- faster in the long run.

But those short cuts require readjusting after adding and removing more elements. Removing isn't a real problem- remove an element and set certain short cuts to point to the next nodes- those cuts that point at the formal n-hundredth nodes. Adding more data is a problem- when adding a new element, certain nodes must be set to point to the previous nodes. In order to get to these elements, the program must go ALL the way trough the list, starting from the last short cut that still points at an n-hundredth element. Unless the nodes also point to the previous elements, the whole process can get as slow as if I am removing an element from a vector.

Is there a way to speed up the access, keeping the processes for adding and removing elements fairly fast? This is just a question of curiosity, not if it is a good idea to use it in a real program.

Answer (score 0):

**You're using the wrong data structure.**  Linked lists are best used for sequentially-accessed lists, not for randomly-accessed collections.  For that, you're better off with a hash table of some sort.

Comment: You missed the "This is just a question of curiosity, not if it is a good idea to use it in a real program." sentence. I understand, that it is not a good idea for random access, but is there a way to speed up the access anyway?

Comment: I didn't miss it, that's my whole point.  Lists are for sequential-access uses, not random-access.